# Let $G$ act on set $S$ with $|G|=3^n, |S|=2021$. Prove $\exists s_1,s_2, {\rm Stab}_G(s_1)={\rm Stab}_G(s_2) = G$ not in the same orbit

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I have a group $G$ acting on set $S$.
$$f : G \times S \rightarrow S$$
$|G| = 3^n$ and $|S| = 2021$. I need to show that there exists two elements $s_1$ and $s_2$, such that ${\rm Stab}_G(s_1) ={\rm Stab}_G(s_2) = G$ and $s_1$ and $s_2$ are not on the same orbit!

I was trying to get and answer using the Dirichlet principle. It didn't work out.

Then I was trying to find some connection with the symmetric group $S_{2021}$. But I can't seem to solve it.

Any tips?

Comment: That follows from $2021 \equiv 2 \bmod 3$.

Comment: The title is asking for a proof of something that is not true in general. The title should be used for giving an idea of the topic of the question, not for an incomplete version of the question itself.

Comment: Why it follows from that ?

Comment: Orbits of points $s$ for which ${\rm Stab}_G(s) \ne G$ have size divisible by $3$, to there must be at least two distinct $s$ with ${\rm Stab}_G(s) = s$.

Comment: Typo.. Should be S. I fixed it.

Comment: Why orbits of points s  ($Stab_G(s) \neq G)$ have size divisible by 3? Is it because $|G| = 3^n$ ?

Comment: Do you not know the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, each orbit's size must be either a proper power of $3$, or $1$. Moreover, $S$ is partitioned into the set of orbits. Therefore, since $2021\equiv 2 \pmod 3$, there must be at least two singleton orbits (whose stabilizers are then the whole $G$).